# Make a simple javascript slideshow random

Tags: javascript

HY, i'am using a very simple slidshow JS script.

```
function slideSwitch() {
  var $active = $('#slideshow div.active');

  if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow div:last');

  var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next()
  : $('#slideshow div:first');

  $active.addClass('last-active');

  $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
  .addClass('active')
  .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
     $active.removeClass('active last-active');
  });
}

$(function() {
  setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 8000 );
});
```

But now i want to let it start with a random slide instead of the pre defined div with the class `<div class="slide active">`.
As far as i can read the script the active slide is used to let te slideshow work and changing it will cause the script to fail?

How can i implement this function?

the HTML code is shown below, use of php is not possible.

```
<div id="slideshow">
  <div class="slide active">
    <a href="link">
      <img src="/image.jpg" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <a href="link">
      <img src="/image.jpg" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <a href="">
      <img src="/image.jpg" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"As far as i can read the script the active slide is used to let te slideshow work and changing it will cause the script to fail?"*

No it's "fail-safe". If there is no `active` slide it will use the last slide.

```
if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow div:last');
```

So just select a random slide and add the `active` class to it.

---

On possible way could be...

Remove the `active` class from the DOM

Add this function

```
function activateRandomSlide() {
    var slides = $("#slideshow .slide"),
        randomIndex = ~~(Math.rand() * slides.length);  // integer in range: 0..(slides.length - 1)

    slides.eq(randomIndex).addClass("active");
}
```

And call it on DOMReady

```
$(function() {
    activateRandomSlide();

    setInterval(slideSwitch, 8000 );
});
```

Example:

```js
function activateRandomSlide() {
  var slides = $("#slideshow .slide"),
    randomIndex = ~~(Math.random() * slides.length); // integer in range: 0..(slides.length - 1)

  slides.eq(randomIndex).addClass("active");
}

$(function() {
  activateRandomSlide();
});
```

```css
#slideshow {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 20px;
}

.slide {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: none
}

.slide.active {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
  <div class="slide">Slide 1</div>
  <div class="slide">Slide 2</div>
  <div class="slide">Slide 3</div>
  <div class="slide">Slide 4</div>
  <div class="slide">Slide 5</div>
  <div class="slide">Slide 6</div>
  <div class="slide">Slide 7</div>
  <div class="slide">Slide 8</div>
  <div class="slide">Slide 9</div>
  <div class="slide">Slide 10</div>
</div>
```